# Why can I not reverse sort arrays like this?

Tags: java

```
int [] numbers = {1,2,3,4};
ReverseSortComparator c = new ReverseSortComparator();

Arrays.sort(c, numbers);
```

Comment: It is a custom comparator defined with a compareTo so that numbers can be compared in descending order

Comment: are you serious? read the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/)...

Comment: Can you show source of ReverseSortComparator?

Comment: you should edit your question to state _exactly_ what the problem is, for example give the error message if there's one. You should also add information about your custom comparator.

Comment: instead of implementing your own comparator, use an existing one (i.e. `Arrays.sort(numbers, Collections.reverseOrder());`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method in `Arrays` that takes a primitive array and a Comparator. You would have to have an Integer array, not an int array.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument must be the array and the second one the `Comparator` :

```
Arrays.sort(numbers, c);
```

You can find more information in  the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) !

Comment: @phoenix Like @Ted said in another answer, there's a good chance you must have an `Integer` array instead of an `int` one. Next time, you can also gives the exact error instead of just stating there's one, this would be really helpful ;)

Comment: yes that fixed it - an Integer array is required and not primitive ints

Answer (score 0):

sort method accept array and comparator

```
<Object> void java.util.Arrays.sort(Object[] a, Comparator<? super Object> c)
```

There is error in your code.